# Determine which perl module needs to be updated

Tags: perl

I am trying to migrate an application which is currently running on `v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi`.
New host on which I am trying to migrate is `perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi`

When I am trying to run the perl script I am getting below error

```
./myapp.pl --start
/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: app/cpan_lib/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/version/vxs/vxs.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Istack_sp_ptr
```

From this error I am not able to identify which Perl module is not compatible to the current Perl Version .

In my Perl script these are the modules which I am including

```
use Getopt::Long;
use File::Spec::Functions;
```

Comment: Wow, these are both ancient versions of Perl!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's "version::vxs" that is part of the "version" CPAN module.

Here's a link: [LEONT / version-0.9929 / vutil / lib / version / vxs.pm](https://metacpan.org/release/LEONT/version-0.9929/source/vutil/lib/version/vxs.pm)

Comment: So do i need to install the updated version ? Only diff I can see is mine has $VERSION = 0.9908; and this one has different version

Comment: You the module to be compiled against your Perl.  The old version might work if it is recompiled or you may need a different version that works with your new Perl version.